# Selecting drop down box does not activate confirm dialog window on Edge browser for Python Selenium WebDriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, microsoft-edge

I'm having trouble with a drop-down box on Microsoft Edge.  This issue doesn't occur on Chrome, Firefox or IE (v9-11).

The command I use to select drop-down box in my code for the other web browsers is the **Select** command:

> Select(driver.find_element_by_id("active_config")).select_by_visible_text(configFile)

Once the config file is selected, a dialog box occurs asking the user to confirm the change.  On Edge, however, the selected config file shows in the drop-down box, but for some reason, the dialog box to confirm the config file change never pops up, so the test fails.

When I manually test the scenario [using my mouse], it works fine.  I also used a sleep timer [in my test] and the mouse to confirm there wasn't something wrong with Edge when it was brought up by Selenium because I've had that occur on rare occasions.  It's almost as if when the file is selected, it's not being selected in a way that causes the confirm dialog action to be executed.  I've tried the various methods below, but nothing seems to do the trick.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='active_config']/option[text()='" + configFile + "']").double_click()
```

<>

```
menu = driver.find_element_by_id("active_config")
submenu = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='active_config']/option[text()='" + configFile + "']")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(menu).click(submenu).perform()
```

<>

```
Select(driver.find_element_by_id("active_config")).select_by_visible_text(configFile)
driver.find_element_by_id("active_config").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

<>

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='active_config']/option").click()
Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("active_config")).select_by_visible_text(configFile)
```

<>

```
Select(driver.find_element_by_id("active_config")).select_by_visible_text(configFile)
Select(driver.find_element_by_id("active_config")).select_by_visible_text(configFile)
```

<>

```
Select(driver.find_element_by_id("active_config")).select_by_visible_text(configFile)
driver.find_element_by_id("active_config").send_keys(Keys.NULL)
```

<>

```
  success = False
     tries = 0
     while success == False:
         try:
             Select(driver.find_element_by_id("active_config")).select_by_visible_text(configFile)
             assertExpectedConditionTrue(self.driver, "By.LINK_TEXT", "Activate "+ configFile)
             success == True
         except NoSuchElementException:
             tries = tries + 1
             if tries == 3:
                 raise Exception ("EDGE WON'T SELECT NEW PROFILE")
             else:
                 time.sleep(1)
```

<>

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='active_config']/option[text()='" + configFile + "']").click()
```

<>

```
Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='active_config']")).select_by_visible_text(configFile)
```

At this point, I'm pretty stumped and don't know what to try.  Suggestions??

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint on that line and stepped through the code and made sure that each line is doing what it's supposed to do?

Comment: So presumably the select element you're having trouble with has an 'onchange' event that doesn't seem to be fired once an option is selected?
Also, is this confirm dialog a modal dialog or a HTML element?

Comment: @TomTrumper , The confirm dialog is a modal dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use Action Chains.

The **.move_to_element().click()** and **Select()** did not work for Edge.  On Chrome, Firefox, and IE, I could point to the location of the drop-down list and a list of profiles would be returned.

```
driver.find_element_by_id("active_config")
```

- OR -

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='active_config']")
```

That was not the case on Edge.  When I would point to the same location on Edge, it would return nothing.  I suspect this is why the 'on charge' event would never occur even though using **Select()** would show the profile I wanted to activate in the box.  I encountered this same issue with other drop-down lists on Edge as well.  Oddly enough, if I pointed to each item in the list separately, I could get Selenium to return its value.

i.e.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='active_config']/option[1]")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='active_config']/option[2]")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='active_config']/option[3]")
ect...
```

Therefore, I had to do the following in order to resolve my issue:

1. Create a list that contains all the config files in order.

   ```
           active_config_list = []
           num_of_active_configs = 0
           new_config_loc = None
           curr_config_loc = None
           try:
               while True:
                   active_config_list.append(self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='active_config']/option[" + str(num_of_active_configs + 1) + "]").text)
                   num_of_active_configs = num_of_active_configs + 1
           except NoSuchElementException:
               pass
   ```
2. Store the location of both the profile that is active & the profile I want to activate.  That way, I know the number of times the 'arrow up' or 'arrow down' key needs to be pushed to highlight the profile file I want.

   ```
           for cnt in xrange(0, num_of_active_configs):
               if self.ncdFile == active_config_list[cnt]:
                   new_config_loc = cnt + 1
                   if not re.search (r"No .ncd file is active.", self.driver.find_element_by_id("active_conf").text) == None:
                       curr_config_loc = 1
                       break
                   else:
                       active_config_string = self.driver.find_element_by_id("active_conf").text.split()
                       for cnt in xrange(0, num_of_active_configs):
                           if str(active_config_string[0]) == active_config_list[cnt]:
                               curr_config_loc = cnt + 1
                               break
                   break
   ```
3. Use Action Chains to activate the list, use the Arrow keys to select the desired profile, and then press Enter.

   ```
       menu = self.driver.find_element_by_id("active_config")

       ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(menu).click(menu).perform()
       if curr_config_loc < new_config_loc:
           for x in xrange(0, new_config_loc - curr_config_loc):
               ActionChains(self.driver).key_down(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).perform()
       elif curr_config_loc > new_config_loc:
           for x in xrange(0, curr_config_loc - new_config_loc):
               ActionChains(self.driver).key_down(Keys.ARROW_UP).perform()
       ActionChains(self.driver).key_down(Keys.ENTER).perform()
   ```